# How do i correctly implement a three way many-to-many relationship in rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, many-to-many

I'm using rails 4 and i have a possible three way many-to-many relationship situation that looks like this: To register a sale, i need a Client and a Product, along with its quantity. The threeway comes when i need a fixed id for the Sale because of another table Installments, with due dates and values for each installment and to check if they are paid or not.

I got a little confused with the relationships between them, but i did something like this (i called the middle table i used here as SCP, sale_client_product):

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :scps
end

class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :scps
  has_many :installments
end

class Installment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sale
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :scps
end

class SCP < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :sale
end
```

I would like to know if this is correct or if there is a better way of doing it. I'm also in a picle when actually saving, as for any one sale i may have to save many SCP instances with one form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have `Product`, `Client`, `Sale`, `Installment` information in a single document, maybe you can use the `Invoice`.

In business, if a company want to ask money from a customer, he will periodically send him an [**invoice**](https://images.sampletemplates.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/26110153/Free-Download-Simple-Invoice-Template.jpg) which includes all the following infos:

- Product details, names, quantity, price for each unit
- Client details, names, address, phone number
- Sale details, total price, date of sale **or** Installment due date, installment amount

---

```
Class Client
  has_many :invoices
end

Class Product
  has_many :invoices
end

Class Sale
  has_many :installments
  has_many :invoices, through: :installments 
end

Class Installment
  belongs_to :sale
end

Class Invoice
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :installment
end
```

---

`Payment` will be what you need to reconcile with `Invoice`, so that you can understand which `Invoices` (and consequently `Installments`) were paid.

```
Class Payment
  belongs_to :invoice
end
```

when you do `@invoice.payment` you get the payment for that invoice (which `belongs_to :installment`), if `@invoice.payment` is `nil`, then the installment was not paid.

If you want to register a `Payment` it should have an existing `Invoice`

```
@payment = Payment.new(payment_params)
@payment.invoice_id = @invoice.id
@payment.save
```

This is kind of how I would register **Accounting Transactions** when I was working in the Accounting Field. Feel free to improve your app and maybe in the future we can edit this post for improvements

A possible improvement could be enstablishing that [`Installment has_one :payment, through: :invoice`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-through-association), so you figure that out!

Comment: Thanks for the help man. I still have to understand better the polymorphic association as i don't know how it works really, i'll get back to you when i get it to work

Comment: Just so i get the idea, you are treating this invoice as a package that includes all products for a specific sale and the client? I'm having trouble understanding the implementation of your example as i don't get what invoice is code wise.

Comment: @onildo you are right. My solution was not complete, so I completely rewrited it. Please have a look. Thanks